# Find the $E[X^3]$ of the normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Find the $E[X^3]$ of the normal distribution with mean μ and variance $σ^2$ (in terms of $μ$ and $σ$).

So far, I have that it is the integral of $x^3$ multiplied with the pdf of the normal distribution, but when I try to integrate it by parts, it becomes super convulated especially with the e term. I know there's tricks with odd and even functions that may apply and I have a sinking suspicion it might just end up being μ, but I've kind of hit a wall. Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT:

So I think the answer is either $0$ (because of how the graph looks when I plotted it) or, by simple integration it is $3μσ^2 + μ^3$.

Comment: Use the moment generating function.

Comment: I may just totally have no idea what's going on in class (possible), but I don't think we learned that? Is there another way to do it or should I learn from google.

Comment: Let $Y=X-\mu$ be centered version of $X$ whose odd moments are zero. Then $E(X^3)=E((Y +\mu)^3)=3E(Y^2)\mu+\mu^3=3\sigma^2\mu+\mu^3$.

Comment: When integrating by parts, are you integrating $x^3$ or the pdf?

Comment: Both? I thought that E[X^3] = ∫x^3 f(x) dx

Comment: You cannot have two answers for such a problem. Either $0$ or $3\mu\sigma^2 + \mu^3$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Solitary well it does for $\mu=0$ which I suspect is what the OP is plotting :).

Comment: Haha that's what I meant, I couldn't figure out which one it was. But yeah air is right, for the general case the answer is not 0. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

You can observe that it is a integral of a impar function over the all domain $\mathbb R$. Therefore it is equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing $x^2$ by $t$ and do the integration by parts.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).